# printing coefficients to cvs excel file using C++ in visual studio

Tags: visual-c++

<< code snippet>>

```
  double coeffIdeal[20], coeffLiquid[20], coeffSolid[20];
  long   coeffIdealSize, coeffLiquidSize, coeffSolidSize;
  compPtr->GetData(THP::HIDEALCOEFS, coeffIdeal, coeffIdealSize, 20);
  compPtr->GetData(THP::HLSATCOEFS, coeffLiquid, coeffLiquidSize, 20);
  compPtr->GetData(THP::HSSATCOEFS, coeffSolid, coeffSolidSize, 20);
  strcpy(CompTab, argv[1]);
  strcat(CompTab, "_coeffs.csv");
  ofstream myfileComp;
  myfileComp.open(CompTab);
  myfileComp << "Name ," << argv[1] <<", Ideal, Liquid, Solid"<< endl;
  myfileComp << "Formula" << endl ;
  myfileComp << "MW     ," << MW << endl;
  myfileComp << "Tc(K)  ," << Tc << endl;
  myfileComp << "NBP(K) ,"<< NBP << endl;
  myfileComp << "NMP(K) ,"<< NMP << endl;
  myfileComp << "Correlation Number ,"  ","<< corrIdeal  << ","  << corrLiquid  << ","   <<    corrSolid  << endl;
  myfileComp << "Factor" "," ","<< conffIdeal << "," << conffLiquid << "," << conffSolid << endl;
  myfileComp << "Coeff" "," << coeffIdeal;
  myfileComp.close();
```

I am trying to print coefficients to excel csv file from visual studio using C++ can someone help me? The coefficients should print in the column in excel.

Comment: You're reading some data from "compPtr" and you're writing it to a .csv with file stream "myfileComp".  So far, so good.  Q: What's going wrong?  Q: Are you sure the data returned by "compPtr->getData()" is correct?  Q: Have you tried looking at the data in the Visual Studio debugger?  Here are two tutorials: [Mastering Debugging with MSVS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn), [Debugging C++ in Visual Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5gBIizwsY0)

Comment: What is the problem? Wrong output? How does your output look and what do you expect?

Comment: How can I write the loop for three groups of coefficients to print to csv file? Thank you

Comment: how can I declare max in C++? I have HICoeff[20] the max size is 20. I need to declare it I used int but it didn't work. Thank you!

Comment: max(coeffIdeal[20], coeffLiquid[20], coeffSolid[20]);
  for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i);
  {
    if (int i = 0); << "coeffIdeal," << ","; 

    if (i < coeffIdealSize); << HIDEALCOEFS[i] << ",";

  }

Comment: Please help with the above loop Thanks!